# Unable to launch AVD when increasing heap size

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, heap-memory

If I increase the AVD's heapSize more than ~750 (750MB) the emulator does not start properly (android services fail to start).

The problem occurs when launching the AVD from android studio:

- emulator gets stuck trying to launch

The problem also occurs when launching from the command-line tools:

- Among others in the logcat output: 
  I/ServiceManager: service 'media.resource_manager' died
- When executing `am` or `pm` command inside the adb shell I get: Segmentation fault.
- When trying to install apk with adb -> can't find service: package

This is a version of the config.ini file when the problem occurs.
Any value for vm.heapSize below 700 works fine.

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
abi.type=x86_64
hw.cpu.arch=x86_64
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.ramSize=6144
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86_64/
skin.name=WVGA800
skin.path=platforms/android-25/skins/WVGA800
tag.display=Google apis
tag.id=google_apis
vm.heapSize=768
disk.dataPartition.size=2048M
```

Changing the other parameters (ramSize etc) do not solve the problem even for huge values (100GB). 
I have verified through the shell that the requested ramSize is indeed allocated:

- cat /proc/meminfo

...and the heap size is the one requested:

- Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() when the emulator starts properly and I am able to install the apk